# "No input file specified" - after updating PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

On the server PHP has been updated from 5.4 to 5.6, and since then I get the following error message: "No input file specified."

I want my links to be like this: www.example.com/products/red-wines/

In my PHP file I used $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to get the complete URL, what I exploded by "/".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: cant test but your rule looks odd..  $1 will have no value since the condition doesn't provide one.. eg; has no (.*)     See if it works correctly by removing $1

Answer (score 0):

The $1 is not getting populated in your current rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note the `(.*)`   a regular expression meaning grab everything after example.com/ and make it available to subsequent rules as a variable $1   If there were two, the 2nd would be available via $2 and so on...

Comment: I've edited as you mentioned, but still the same error message.